# MVVM control of Adapter

Tags: android, mvvm

Just started implementing MVVM arch in our project and was wondering, how does `ViewModel` control `Adapter`?

I do not want to hold duplicate data lists (One in adapter, second one in `ViewModel`) because that does not sound right. How to solve this?

Comment: In my opinion the best option would be to have LiveDataAdapter, doesn't seem impossible to adapt from standard adapters. Might be worth a try. Looking forward real answers because your question is very interesting

Answer (score 0):

class ViewContrillerAdapter: NSObject {

```
private let cellIdentifier = "cell"
weak var delegate: ViewControllerAdapterDelegate?
private var tablview: UITableView
var item: [DataList] = [] {
    didSet {
        setup()
    }
}


init(tablview: UITableView) {
    self.tablview = tablview
    self.tablview.register(UINib(nibName: "ListTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    super.init()
    self.tablview.delegate = self
    self.tablview.dataSource = self
}

func setup() {
    tablview.reloadData()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblList: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        setUpAdapter()
        apiCalling()
        bindInfoViewModel()
    }
}
private var adapter : ViewContrillerAdapter?
private var list: [DataList] = [] {
    didSet {
        bindInfoViewModel()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func setUpAdapter() {
    adapter = ViewContrillerAdapter(tablview: tblList)
    adapter?.delegate = self
}
func bindInfoViewModel(){
    adapter?.item = list
}
```

}